# Kotlin: Acessing function asynchronously

Tags: android, kotlin

I accessed a function that returns array for my RecyclerView. How do i load the array async?
I load the function as such:

```
var content = ContentList().list(navBarTitle)
```

ContentList class:

```
class ContentList {

    fun list(title : String):Array<Array<Int>>
    {
        var contentTitle : Array<Array<Int>>
        if (title == "Hijaiyyah Letters")
            contentTitle = arrayOf(
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_1, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_2, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_3, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_4, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_5, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_6, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_7, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_8, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_9, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_10, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_11, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_12, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_13, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_14, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_15, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_16, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_17, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_18, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_19, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_20, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_21, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_22, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_23, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_24, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_25, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_26, R.raw.blurp_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_27, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_28, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_29, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_30, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_intro1_31, R.raw.blurp_x)
            )
        else if(title == "Fat-hah Vowel 1")
            contentTitle = arrayOf(
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_1, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_2, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_3, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_4, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_fathah1_5, R.raw.blurp_x)
            )
        else
            contentTitle = arrayOf(
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_tbr, R.raw.ahem_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_tbr, R.raw.bad_disk_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_tbr, R.raw.baseball_hit),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_tbr, R.raw.bloop_x),
                arrayOf(R.drawable.ic_tbr, R.raw.blurp_x)
            )
        return contentTitle
    }
}
```

I still have lots more to populate the array but already the app is lagging so i i am thinking of async approach. I googled for Kotlin async methods but saw its about creating new function for it?  Any pointers/advise is very much appreciated. Millions of thanx in advance...

Comment: Check out Kotlin Coroutines: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kotlin `coroutine`. You can try below code

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    val content = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ContentList().list(navBarTitle)
    }
    // result will have returned value of `list()` function
    var result = content.await() 
   }
}
```

As, we are accessing `list()` from coroutine, it needs to be `suspend` function

```
suspend fun list(title : String): Array<Array<Int>> { }
```

Comment: Getting error from the IDE `Expecting member declaration` to my preceding line: `recyclerView_main.adapter = SecondAdapter(content)`... Any idea?