# How to perform heavy database operations with room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm using a room database to run some heavy database operation. I am not using LiveData for this operation as I use the result for computation only. Now if in my main fragment I have this

```kotlin
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val result = viewModel.someHeavyOperation() // a suspend fun
        doSomething(result)
    }
}
```

I get a `Skipped xx frames! Your application might be doing to much work on main thread.` on startup which I don't get if I leave out the database query.

Now some answers here like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57657797) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265349) seem to suggest running the query on IO thread, like

```kotlin
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val result = viewModel.someHeavyOperation() // a suspend fun
        }
        doSomething(result)
    }
}
```

which does increase performance for me. What confuses me though is that in [an article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-iii-real-work-2ba8a2ec2f45) by the android developers publication on medium it says

> Note: Room uses its own dispatcher to run queries on a background thread. Your code should not use withContext(Dispatchers.IO) to call suspending room queries. It will complicate the code and make your queries run slower.

However, they only seem to consider the case where the expensive bits are the ensuing calculations, where they seem to suggest something like

```kotlin
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val result = viewModel.someOperation() // a suspend fun
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            doSomethingHeavy(result)
        }
    }
}
```

So now my questions:

1. Why should it matter from which dispatcher room queries are called if room uses a custom dispatcher anyways?
2. How to perform expensive room queries without blocking the main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why should it matter from which dispatcher room queries are called if room uses a custom dispatcher anyways?

Room introduced `Kotlin Coroutine` support from version `2.1` onwards. Earlier, they were not supporting `Coroutine`. So, first of all, make sure if your room version is `2.1` or above from `build.gradle` file :

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:${versions.room}"
```

If you're using `Room` version older than `2.1`, then `Room` will perform operations on caller thread. This means that if we give query call of Room on `MAIN` thread, it'll execute operations on `MAIN`. If we give call to Room on `IO - background` thread, it'll execute on `background`.

> How to perform expensive room queries without blocking the main thread?

For this, we should call Room queries on `IO` thread. You are already doing correct thing

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val result = viewModel.someHeavyOperation() // a suspend fun
        }
        doSomething(result)
    }
}
```

In addition to it, if you need to add waiting until Room query call returns, you can use `async` launcher and `await()` method

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
    val content = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        viewModel.someHeavyOperation() // a suspend fun
    }
    // Using below line, we are introducing waiting for completion of someHeavyOperation() on IO thread
    // If we return any result from someHeavyOperation(), it can be accessed in result variable as below
    var result = content.await() 
    }
   }
}
```

Reference :

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376666/1994950
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59408634/1994950

Comment: So why does the [medium article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-iii-real-work-2ba8a2ec2f45) say we shouldn't call room queries from IO thread?

Comment: I cited it in my question: "Note: Room uses its own dispatcher to run queries on a background thread. Your code should not use withContext(Dispatchers.IO) to call suspending room queries. It will complicate the code and make your queries run slower."

Comment: Okay, as I have mentioned, after Room version `2.1`, the recommendation is not to use `IO` thread from developer side as Room is doing it for us. But, if our legacy code is using Room version below `2.1`, developer need to handle it.

Comment: It is recommendation, not rule. We can still use `IO` as good practise with `2.1` version of `Room`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I use version `2.2.3`, but my code runs faster with `Dispatchers.IO`. I assume it is because of complexities introduced in the ViewModel/Repository code ...